# Omit certain lines from tail -f

Tags: tail

I like `tail -f` but I like to omit lines that have a certain string in them. 
Is this possible?
I have seen example to include certain string but not how to omit.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Answer (score 6):

```
tail -f /path/to/file | grep -v CertainText
```